# using tar to extract latest .gz file into another directory

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

# Location for backups to be saved.

EXTRACTTO=/opt/test_script

#stores the latest .gz file to be extracted

EXTRACTFROM= ls -t /opt/scripts/AXDB1.clean_pof_backup* | head -1

echo $EXTRACTFROM

tar -xf $EXTRACTFROM -C $EXTRACTTO
```

EXTRACTTO contains the path where I want to extract my .gz files to.

EXTRACTFROM contains the latest .gz file, which will be extracted.

However when I pass this variables which contains directory path, in tar command

it gives invalid directory error.

Can someone tell how can I accomplish my task here?

Comment: Can you rerun the script with sh -x and post the output?  Otherwise, the EXTRACTFROM= needs to be EXTRACTFROM=<virgule>whatever_cmd<virgule> and you should check for null/failure before executing the tar.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, it seems that EXTRACTTO is incorrect.  Print it out and try running the tar command manually.

Comment: EXTRCTTO prints /opt/test_script. Which is a valid directory.

Comment: change the last line to: echo tar -xf $EXTRACTFROM -C $EXTRACTTO  and then run that command.